# swagger-parser 1.0.57 provided additional responsesObject field to the parsed swagger definition

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, jackson-databind

I'm using swagger-parser 1.0.57 version and when I'm inputting swagger2 definition to the parser,the output of [swagger](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore.yaml) after being parsed gives the following.

```
/pets/{petId}:
get:
  summary: Info for a specific pet
  operationId: showPetById
  tags:
    - pets
  parameters:
    - name: petId
      in: path
      required: true
      description: The id of the pet to retrieve
      type: string
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Expected response to a valid request
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Pets'
    default:
      description: unexpected error
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  responsesObject:
    "200":
      description: Expected response to a valid request
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Pets'
    default:
      description: unexpected error
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

Above content provides issue in swagger-editor since repsponsesObject.
[image]

To remove the reposesObject as a workaround I wrote following code with the swagger parser.

```
SwaggerParser parser = new SwaggerParser();
    SwaggerDeserializationResult parseAttemptForV2 = parser.readWithInfo(oasDefinition);
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(parseAttemptForV2.getMessages())) {
        log.debug("Errors found when parsing OAS definition");
    }
    parseAttemptForV2.setSwagger(removeResponsesObject(parseAttemptForV2.getSwagger()));
    return parseAttemptForV2.getSwagger();

private Swagger removeResponsesObject(Swagger swagger) {
    Swagger modifiedSwagger = swagger;
    if (modifiedSwagger != null && modifiedSwagger.getPaths() != null) {
        Map<String, Path> pathMap = modifiedSwagger.getPaths();
        for (String pathKey : modifiedSwagger.getPaths().keySet()) {
            Path path = modifiedSwagger.getPath(pathKey);
            Map<HttpMethod, Operation> operationMap = path.getOperationMap();
            for (Map.Entry<HttpMethod, Operation> entry : operationMap.entrySet()) {
                Operation operation = entry.getValue();
                if (operation.getResponses() == null) {
                    operation.setResponses(operation.getResponsesObject());
                }
                if (operation.getResponsesObject() != null) {
                    operation.setResponsesObject(null);
                    path.set(entry.getKey().name(), operation);
                }

            }

            pathMap.put(pathKey, path);
        }
        modifiedSwagger.setPaths(pathMap);
        return modifiedSwagger;
    }
    return swagger;
}
```

When I debugging it  reponsesObject is setting as null, but after that it will again appears. I'm not sure this process is having a default multithread envorionment. Any suggetsions to imrprove the code to remove responsesObject?

Answer (score 0):

Sound similar to the issues reported at

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2944

we solved it by applying in our code these mixins:

```java
        mapper.addMixIn(RefModel.class, IgnoreOriginalRefMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(RefProperty.class, IgnoreOriginalRefMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(RefPath.class, IgnoreOriginalRefMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(RefParameter.class, IgnoreOriginalRefMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(RefResponse.class, IgnoreOriginalRefMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(Operation.class, OperationResponseMixin.class);
        mapper.addMixIn(Response.class, ResponseSchemaMixin.class);
```